# Replace text from file for each lines

Tags: python

I want to add new string to all line in a text file.

I have written this program so far:

```
with open("texte.txt", mode="r") as mf:
    for line in mf:
        data = line + '"'
        print(data)
```

But when I print the content, I get an output like this :

```
line
"
line2
"
line3
"
line"
```

So I can see it's my first line from my text which is printed OK.

I want my output to be like this :

```
line1"
line2"
line3"
```

Thanks for your assistance, I hope you understand me

Comment: You need to remove the line break. Try: `data = line.rstrip() + '"'`

Comment: @Prune answer me before but that's what i need exactly

Answer (score 5):

Each line in a file ends with a line feed.  You have to `strip` that character out of the read input before you're ready to work with the remaining string:

```
data = line.rstrip() + '"'
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what i want. Thanks a lot if you have any documentation it will be better for understand

Comment: Just what documentation do you want, that you haven't already found?

Comment: Like for edit texte / string in python i'm not sure to find the right docuementation

Comment: Then you have some *very* basic research skills to work on.  For starters, consult the tutorials and official documentation for the `str` data type.  Teaching you how to do this is not a Stack Overflow issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [splitlines()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=splitlines#str.splitlines) method:

```
with open("texte.txt", mode="r") as mf:
    lines = mf.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        data = line + '"'
        print(data)
```